# Difference between various "calculation" words (演算, 算出, and 計算)

Tags: word-choice, usage

Is there a difference in usage between these words?

1. 演算 (えんざん)
2. 算出  (さんしゅつ)
3. 計算 (けいさん)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

演算 is an operation. When you apply an operation, such as a boolean NOT, you could use this word.

計算 is a computation, a calculation. Morally, it involves many operations. It is also the word for formal calculi in the scientific domain (such as "lambda calculus" or "pi calculus")

I never encountered 算出 and I therefore do not know its usage and nuances. However, a quick check on the internet give a few compound words where it appears to express the result (出) of a computation: 算出税額: calculated tax amount, and 算出金額: calculated amount.

P!